# Botões do menu HTML não funcionam

Tags: html, jquery, css, menu, layout-responsivo

Boa noite galera, estou fazendo um mini website para a prova 1 de Programação Web da faculdade, mas houveram alguns problemas no mesmo.

Fiz um menu responsivo, com dropdown e collapse para quando o tamanho da tela for pequeno, porém NENHUM botão do menu funciona, eles estão configurados corretamente no , o href está correto, mas continuam não funcionando. E pra ficar mais estranho ainda, os submenus do dropdown, que estão escritos DA MESMA MANEIRA de qualquer outra opção do menu, funcionam, mesmo o arquivo requisitado não existindo, eles abrem a página de erro de "arquivo não encontado".

Abaixo segue meu código HTML e CSS utilizados:

https://codepen.io/joaocasarin/pen/xxKmboY

por favor, me ajudem, não faço ideia do que seja, e nem meus amigos sabem.

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Tibia</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.nav li.dropdown").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu").stop(true, true).fadeToggle(100);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topo">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/Tibia.png" alt="Tibia Logo" height="80"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid socialmedia">
            <a href="https://pt-br.facebook.com/tibia/" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tibiabrcom/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/tibia" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#alvo">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="alvo">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/Tibia_icon.png" height="32px"></a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="cadastro.html" data-toggle="tab">Cadastro</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="calendario.html" data-toggle="tab">Calendário</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contato.html" data-toggle="tab">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.html" data-toggle="tab">Galeria</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="posts.html" data-toggle="tab">Posts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        Vocations
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_target">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="druid.html">Druid</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="knight.html">Knight</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="paladin.html">Paladin</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sorcerer.html">Sorcerer</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="corpo">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edit
------ Eu testei aqui e esta funcionando seu menu, ve se os arquivos estao na mesma pasta, ve se os nomes estao certos. ps: eu até comentaria, mas não tenho reputação...

Comment: Mesmo os arquivos não estando na mesma pasta, os menus knight, druid, sorcerer e paladin funcionam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara o seu problema é que vc colocou "aleatoriamente" `data-toggle="tab"` na sua tag `<a>`. Pq vc fez isso? Não faz sentido algum, esse `data-toggle` é para ser usado em em conjunto com o componente de `Tabs` do Bootstrap, com certeza tem algum JavaScript que usa o *dataset* `data-toggle` para executar alguma função, e nessa função deve ter algo como `.preventDefault()` que está impedindo o funcionamento normal do seu link.

Bastou remover o  `data-toggle="tab"` da tag `<a>` da `navbar` que os links passaram a funcionar normalmente!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Tibia</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.nav li.dropdown").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu").stop(true, true).fadeToggle(100);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topo">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/Tibia.png" alt="Tibia Logo" height="80"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid socialmedia">
            <a href="https://pt-br.facebook.com/tibia/" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tibiabrcom/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/tibia" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#alvo">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="alvo">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/Tibia_icon.png" height="32px"></a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="cadastro.html">Cadastro</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="calendario.html">Calendário</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contato.html">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.html">Galeria</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="posts.html">Posts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        Vocations
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_target">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="druid.html">Druid</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="knight.html">Knight</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="paladin.html">Paladin</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sorcerer.html">Sorcerer</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="corpo">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mas se eu tirar o data-toggle, o menu continua funcionando normalmente? eu fiz isso pq meu professor fez lol

Comment: @casarin cara talvez seu professor tenha usado isso em outro momento e vc pegou e usou no menu. De qq forma, se vc tiver vai ver que seu menu funciona normalmente, os links ficam clicáveis etc. Faça o teste vc mesmo e depois me conta aqui de resolveu ou se vc teve problemas ;) Se vc achar que a resposta resolveu o problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setas ao lado da resposta.